# Order by issue when outer joining two tables in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, join, flask, sqlalchemy

I am a noob trying to use flask with sqlalchemy and am having an issue sorting result from a base query.

I have a parent table and two joined many-to-many association tables:

```
class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    (...)
    qty_stock = db.Column(db.Integer)
    requested_products = db.relationship('RequestedProducts')
    ordered_products = db.relationship('OrderedProducts')

class OrderedProducts(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'orderedproducts'
    order_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('order.id'), primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'), primary_key=True)
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer, default=1)
    qty_delivered = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    product = db.relationship('Product', backref='order_assocs')

class RequestedProducts(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'requestedproducts'
    request_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('request.id'), primary_key=True)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'), primary_key=True)
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer, default=1)
    qty_supplied = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    product = db.relationship('Product', backref='request_assocs')
```

In my view class there are 4 table columns for each product showing stock quantity, number of requested products, number of ordered products and a net stock amount, which is basically (stock quantity - requested + ordered). This is the query for the net stock values I'm trying to get working:

```
products = Product.query.filter_by(active_flg=True)
    .filter_by(category_id=int(g.category_id))
    .outerjoin(Product.requested_products)
    .outerjoin(Product.ordered_products)
    .group_by(Product.id)
#Count requested amount for each product
reqs = func.coalesce((func.sum(RequestedProducts.quantity) - func.sum(RequestedProducts.qty_supplied)), 0)
#Count ordered amount for each product
ords = func.coalesce((func.sum(OrderedProducts.quantity) - func.sum(OrderedProducts.qty_delivered)), 0)
result = (Product.qty_stock - reqs + ords)
products = products.order_by(result.desc())
```

Now, the functions work as expected, the only problem is with the order_by function - the order is scrambled. I've found out that the cause is probably in the double outer join. Does anyone have an idea how to deal with that?

Also, I am really a beginner with sqlalchemy and flask so I'd be very grateful for any advice or a better solution (executable with my limited skills). Thank you!

Comment: what database do you use?

Comment: Sqlite for development, MySQL on the server. The sorting issue occurs on both.

Comment: Strange, i copied your code and it works fine on `sqlite`. On this note: do you not want to see partial sums in your views as well (`reqs`, `ords` and `result`)?

Comment: Yes, I have those defined as @hybrid_property in my models.py and then use them in the view class. Unfortunatelly, I haven't found a way how to implement these custom properties in the sorting logic. It says that Instrumented Attributes cannot be iterated or something like that.

Comment: By the way, the sorting issue doesn't seem to be completely random. There are nice sequences going from higher values to lower ones, but then trere's kind of a "jump" and the value increases again.

I forgot to mention there are several makers for one category that are filtered like so:

products = products.filter(Product.maker_id == int(g.maker_id))

and some additional conditions. So the final query is quite complicated. But the sorting should be fine as it is now, right?

Comment: It is difficult to say. Maybe you could share the `SQL` statement that is produced when you run it.

Comment: Here it is (thanks for the help BTW):  
SELECT product.id AS product_id (...)
FROM product 
LEFT OUTER JOIN requestedproducts ON product.id = requestedproducts.product_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN orderedproducts ON product.id = orderedproducts.product_id 
WHERE product.active_flg = :active_flg_1 AND product.category_id = :category_id_1 
GROUP BY product.id 
ORDER BY ((product.qty_stock - coalesce(sum(requestedproducts.quantity) - sum(requestedproducts.qty_supplied), :param_1)) + coalesce(sum(orderedproducts.quantity) - sum(orderedproducts.qty_delivered), :param_2)) DESC, product.maker_id, product.code

Comment: are you sure that no `NULL` values are produced by the expression in `ORDER BY`? maybe some columns do have `NULL` values and the whole expression is `NULL`, and this is why sorting does not work... because otherwise the query looks good.

Comment: There are NULL values! A product may or may not be requested/ordered, so, naturally, NULL values are unavoidable. But I thought the coalesce function would take care of those...

Comment: well, execute your statement in the SQL Management Studio, and see if the result is what you expect.

Comment: You're right! It returns `NULL` values! My understanding of the coalesce function was wrong. Nevertheless, I just tried to use `IFNULL` function instead and the result was the same...

Comment: Check each part of the expression separately to know which one produces `NULL`s. Maybe you have `Product.qty_stock` values that are `NULL`. Your understanding of `COALESCE` and `IFNULL` might not be wrong at all, but you get `NULL`s on another level completely.

Comment: Okay, I've probably found the real cause. It really seems to be the double outer join. When I use only one outer join, the values for either requests or orders sum up correctly, but the second outer join statement makes some of the values to be summed twice. Is there any way around that?

Comment: you need to sum them separately, and there is no work-around for that.

Comment: Thank you for your continuing help! I'm trying to sum them separately with a subquery like this: SELECT product.id as prodid, code (...)(select ifnull(sum(requestedproducts.quantity) - sum(requestedproducts.qty_supplied), 0)) from product left outer join requestedproducts ON requestedproducts.product_id = product.id where requestedproducts.product_id = prodid) as reqdelta, (the same thing for orders) as orddelta FROM product WHERE (...) ORDER BY (qty_stock - reqdelta + orddelta). It works, but the problem now is with python, since I don't know how to access 'prodid' in subqueries. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already really use Hybrid Attributes for partial sums, then it should be pretty easy to combine them together.

```
class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    qty_stock = db.Column(db.Integer)
    requested_products = db.relationship('RequestedProducts')
    ordered_products = db.relationship('OrderedProducts')

    @hybrid_property
    def diff_orders(self):
        return sum(op.quantity - op.qty_delivered
                   for op in self.ordered_products)

    @diff_orders.expression
    def diff_orders(cls):
        return (db.select([db.func.coalesce(
            db.func.sum(
                db.func.coalesce(
                    OrderedProducts.quantity - OrderedProducts.qty_delivered, 0)
            ), 0)])
            .where(OrderedProducts.product_id == cls.id)
            .label("diff_orders")
        )

    @hybrid_property
    def diff_requests(self):
        return sum(op.quantity - op.qty_supplied
                   for op in self.requested_products)

    @diff_requests.expression
    def diff_requests(cls):
        return (db.select([db.func.coalesce(
            db.func.sum(
                db.func.coalesce(
                    RequestedProducts.quantity - RequestedProducts.qty_supplied, 0)
            ), 0)])
            .where(RequestedProducts.product_id == cls.id)
            .label("diff_requests")
        )
```

In which case usage can be similar to:

```
products = db.session.query(
    Product,
    # Product.diff_orders,
    # Product.diff_requests,
    # Product.qty_stock + Product.diff_requests - Product.diff_orders,
).order_by((Product.qty_stock + Product.diff_requests - Product.diff_orders).desc())
for x in products:
    print(x)
```

Comment: It worked! I am still learning the basics so I had no idea you could define those expressions in model class too. Your explanation and patience has been extremely helpful! Thank you so much!!

Comment: What does coalesce do? I'm so confused as to why that works! But thank you!

Comment: @AlexWaters: just google it, and you will get find this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx